# Where to put semantically meaningfull blocks in twitter bootstrap skeleton?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is my first question, so please, do not judge strictly. The essence is in follows: I imagine block structure of document as a printing press - but very remotely, of course - because press already hase content and semantic, while div's structure of document - only skeleton for it, and both mentioned subjects must be added. An object of concern to me is where I should put this semantic in document skeleton, formed with twitter bootstrap and defining structure - for example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
      Content, which must be wrapped in some semantically meaningfull element -    like, for example - article-preview class
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I see two different ways, but dont know, what way is better practice in marking down html documents:

1) Adding semantic class to element, which already have class that forming my document structure - col-xs-12 - or press in my analogy.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 article-preview">
        'Content, which must be wrapped in some semantically meaningfull element like, for example - article-preview class'
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2) Or adding brand new semanit block under structuring block and putting my content here:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="article-preview">
      Content, which must be wrapped in some semantically meaningfull element -    like, for example - article-preview class
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I apologize if the question seems a little stupid to you, but I thinking about it for really long time and from now on can not do anything until it is resolved.

Thank you!

Comment: I think #1 is enough for me. #2 will just add to the size of the html file. Anyway, I think this is off-topic in SO, because the answers you may receive are primarily opinion-based

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer the second way. Because bootstrap cols have their own styles and structure,  so if you have additional styles or codes try to do like second way.

I think we should keep the bootstrap structure.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I also use second approach for reasons of readability and separation of concepts, but a worm of doubt was toring me since the moment mentor from my previous work noticed that he prefferes first way and recommended me to use it, appealing to that prinring press concept, but I suggest when whole analogy is right if use it like 1), it, at the same time, not very suitable because it forces me to tie my skeleton to only specific content and semantic and makes thing difficult if I want to change it via JS

Comment: if you have more styles in the class, then  u go with the second one. I think we should keep the structure of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the first approach because I feel the second approach will make your code long unnecessarily.

With the first approach as well you can add your custom styles. just add your stylesheet after the bootstrap css.

Comment: I use bem css, so wont this approach contradict whole bem block conception?

Comment: No I don't think so.. why should it contradict with the bem structure just keep the bootstrap classes intact and follow your own bem structure.